# Can't pull from /system/bin

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, adb, system

Ok so I'm trying to adb pull some files from /system/bin and adb states that file doesn't exist (yes it does exist) it's same thing with /system/xbin while pulling from /system/lib/ works just fine.
I dont have root, and permissions for all folders are 755.
Any solutions?

Comment: I am not entirely sure but I think you need root in order to do so

Comment: @DeepakGangwar Than why I can pull files from /system/lib/ ? it has same permissions like /bin/ and /xbin/ (755), also it states that file doesn't exist not that permission is denied.